# Arrow in sequence diagram is too short for text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm struggling with pgf-umlsd. As you can see in the image the arrow does not "grow" with my text length, producing a very ugly layout:

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes, shadows, positioning, trees}
\usepackage[underline=false,rounded corners=false]{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

  \begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{t}{Teilnehmer}{}
    \newinst{s}{Server}{}

    \begin{call}{t}{Anfrage}{s}{Parameter $P=e(K,K_{pub})$}
    \end{call}

  \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

I tried using a box with `\begin{call}{t}{Anfrage}{s}{\makebox[10em]{Parameter $P=e(K,K_{pub})$}}` but this doesn't change the result, no matter if I put it to the top or bottom arrow. Is there a possibility to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the `\newinst` with an optional argument: `\newinst[3]{s}{Server}`
(see the [documentation](https://pgf-umlsd.googlecode.com/git/release/pgf-umlsd-0.6/pgf-umlsd-manual.pdf), example 1.1.4; unfortunately, the documentation is not very "talkative" and does explain almost exclusively by example; the source `pgf-umlsd.sty` might be helpful: all commands are listed with a full usage example).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes, shadows, positioning, trees}
\usepackage[underline=false,rounded corners=false]{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

  \begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{t}{Teilnehmer}
    \newinst[3]{s}{Server}

    \begin{call}{t}{Anfrage}{s}{Parameter $P=e(K,K_{pub})$}
    \end{call}

  \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]